# What is issue in my code (Future Payments Server-Side Integration)

Tags: php, ios, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Here is my php code please find error.code refrence from here 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md

```
 $acces_token="A103.LhXuh7MZlAXK-4Vw6jJn9Q7m__ncsJHMDkkpUouekljaXxoNoCGNVkQanDcp9Jyt.9s7Yk5J9UoulgI3aGZNgZp3pwPy";
    $Metadata_id="28c5sss8d309db24639bb1b76ca2419a850";
    $data=array(
        "intent"=>"authorize",
           "payer"=>array(
        "payment_method"=>"paypal"
           ),
           "transactions"=>array(
               array( "amount"=>array(
        "currency"=>"USD",
                    "total"=>"1.88"
               ),
                 "description"=>"future of sauces")
           ));

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init( "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment" );

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id: ' . $Metadata_id,
                 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $acces_token
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string

        )
    );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    $information = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($information);die;
```

**Response is**

```
{"name":"PERMISSION_DENIED","message":"No permission for the requested operation","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#PERMISSION_DENIED","debug_id":"4fb7372e76089"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to enable permission for your app in order to use future payments. To check your permissions:

1. go to http://developer.paypal.com/ and log in
2. go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus there you can see what permits you have.

You can also get some information about going live with your app here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

Comment: To piggyback here, if you go to the developer dashboard (https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/) and load up the application you are using, you will see a section for "App feature options". Under there, make sure to click "Accept Payments", then select "Advanced Options", and select "Future Payments".

Comment: I have alredy enable future payments permission in my app and using developer dashboard.but not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array ( [url] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment [content_type] => application/json [http_code] => 403 [header_size] => 591 [request_size] => 518 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.439073 [namelookup_time] => 0.178351 [connect_time] => 0.447411 [pretransfer_time] => 1.024267 [size_upload] => 153 [size_download] => 187 [speed_download] => 129 [speed_upload] => 106 [download_content_length] => 187 [upload_content_length] => 153 [starttransfer_time] => 1.438986 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 173.0.82.78 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 115.112.59.164 [local_port] => 60697 [request_header] => POST /v1/payments/payment HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: User-Agent: curl/7.39.0 Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com Authorization: Bearer A103.RRu4uS7eBHp_c9ULBbKVfd6cRo6vn9p4Qw6Y5gP-DgduoyqFvUF_HY2Y0xHCeTYw.EVQISeVeN40Sa_SM9uwz4dx4EW0 PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id:d35d336b453d44a8bff1315077eb5c10 Accept: application/json Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 153 )
```